# create 2 different tabs in the same page

Tags: jquery, css, html

Would you please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhussein/20psbpdj/) and let me know how I can update the code to have 2 different tabs, so when the user click on the Student Search first tab the dashboard tab remain active.

Below is the code I'm using to activate/show/hide the tabs

```
 $(function () {
        $('ul.tabs li:first').addClass('active');
        $('.block article').hide();
        $('.block article:first').show();
        $('ul.tabs li').on('click', function () {
            $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active')
            $('.block article').hide();
            var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            $(activeTab).show();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: why u are not using jquery tabs?

Comment: So when student click on Main Search then dashboard should be visible and active, correct ?

Comment: I've tried jquery tabs but unable to find a solution for this problem. let me know if you have any sample with 2 different tabs.

Comment: @AbuYazan I have posted my answer with jquery tabs

Comment: Yes one tab from each section should be active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Jquery tabs. when something is already available then why bother to do something again

here is the jquery solution

```js
  $(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#tabs1").tabs();
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
      aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
      nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>

  </div>


  <div id="tabs1">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
        leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
        Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
        aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat.
        Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
        nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
      <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit,
        magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum
        rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/20psbpdj/9/

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.tabs li:first').addClass('active');
    $('.block article').hide();

    $('.block article:first-child').show();

    $('ul.tabs li').on('click', function () {

        $(this).parents('.panel').find('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');

        $(this).addClass('active');

        $(this).parents('.panel').find('.block article').hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $(activeTab).show();
        return false;
        });
    });
```

Also, add $('.block article:first-child').show(); to make the first tab of the second block show after loading.

Edit: Updated with active tabs for two panels.

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine your code for the current parent.

**Find this line:**

```
$("ul.tabs li").removeClass('active');
```

The above line generically, not for the particular tab, resets all the tabs. So what you need is to find the parent `.tabs` container and reset only to that.

And replace it with this:

```
$(this).closest(".tabs").find("li").removeClass('active');
```

#### Fiddle:

```js
$(function () {
  $('ul.tabs li:first-child').addClass('active');
  $('.block article').hide();
  $('.block article:first-child').show();
  $('ul.tabs li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest(".tabs").find("li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $('.block article').hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(activeTab).show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
.wrapper {
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0em;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.tabs li {
  border: gray solid 1px;
  border-bottom: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
  padding: .25em .5em;
}
ul.tabs li a {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.tabs li.active {
  background: #2fa4e7;
}
ul.tabs li.active a {
  color: white;
}
.clr {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
article {
  border-top: gray solid 1px;
  padding: 0 0em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="dvMain">
    <form method="post" id="SearchForm" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" id="divSearch">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSearch">
                Student Search
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseMainSearch" class="panel-body panel-collapse collapse in">
            <section class="wrapper">
              <ul class="tabs">
                <li id="first"><a href="#MainS">Main Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ACSS">Academic Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#AttS">Attendance Search</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="clr"></div>
              <section class="block">
                <article id="MainS">
                  Main search
                </article>
                <article id="ACSS">
                  Academic serach
                </article>
                <article id="AttS">
                  Attendance serach
                </article>
                <article id="StaS">
                  status serach
                </article>
              </section>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div id="divSecondPanel" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

        <div class="panel panel-primary" id="divDashboard">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseDashboard">
                Dashboard
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseDashboard" class="panel-body panel-collapse collapse in">
            <section class="wrapper">
              <ul class="tabs">
                <li id="second"><a href="#tab1">Students by Division</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2">Students by Campus</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3">Students by Level</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="clr"></div>
              <section class="block">
                <article id="tab1">
                  division
                </article>
                <article id="tab2">
                  campus
                </article>
                <article id="tab3">
                  level
                </article>
              </section>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Just change `:first` to `:first-child` for what you need!

Comment: can you update the code to make the first tab in dashboard active?

Comment: Sure... I am doing it.

Comment: @AbuYazan Just change `:first` to `:first-child` for what you need!

Comment: @AbuYazan Can you check if it is okay?

Comment: thanks the solution is OK, but I like the jqiery solution submitted by Alex.

Comment: Well, this is also jQuery solution only.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
    $(function () {
        $('ul.tabs li:first').addClass('active');
        $('.block article').hide();
        $('.block article:first').show();
        $('ul.tabs li').on('click', function () {
            $(this).parents('.tabs').find('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active')
          $(this).parents('.wrapper').find('article').hide();
            var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            $(activeTab).show();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/20psbpdj/7/

Comment: your code removing the content from first selection

Comment: @Alex can you update the code to have 1 active tab for each section?

Comment: @AbuYazan check my answer. You have that

Comment: Thanks to all of you, are solutions are working fine, I choose @Alex solution.